# Is two-way referencing more efficient in Mongo for a 1 to N relationship?

Tags: mongodb

I have a discussion at work about two-way referencing in a 1 to N relationship. [According to this post in MongoDB blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2), you can do it. We wouldn't need atomic updates at all, so no problem there. Following the example in the article, in our case you can only create or delete task but not change the task owner.

My argument is that two-way referencing is probably more efficient for fetching data from both sides, as we will need to display more often the owner with their tasks and less often just the tasks, in different parts of the program. My colleague says there won't be an efficiency gain and the data duplication is not worth it.

Do you have any info about the efficiency of this approach?

Answer (score 3):

De-normalizing and storing the data helps when we have less write and more read. Here the efficiency depends upon how the data is retrieved. If our retrieval of data from the collections requires two way referencing and if we already have it then certainly it improves the efficiency of our query.

**Student collection**

```
 { _id:1, name: "Joseph", courses:[1, 3, 4]}
 { _id:2, name: "Mary", courses:[1, 3]}
 { _id:3, name: "Catherine", courses:[1, 2, 4]}
 { _id:4, name: "Robert", courses:[2, 4]}
```

**Course Collection**

```
 { _id:1, name: "Math101", students: [1, 2, 3]}
 { _id:2, name: "Science101", students: [3, 4]}
 { _id:3, name: "History101", students: [1, 2]}
 { _id:4, name: "Astronomy101", students: [1, 3, 4]}
```

Consider the above example of Students and Courses, here two way referencing is done, the courses array in Students collection gives us the different courses studied by the student. Similarly the Students array in the Courses collection gives us the students who are studying the respective course.

If we want to list the students who were studying Math101 then the query would be

```
db.courses.aggregate([{$match: {name:"Math101"}},
  {$unwind:"$students"},
  {$lookup:{from:"students", 
            localField:"students", 
            foreignField:"_id", 
            as:"result"}}])
```

[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in the aggregation pipeline are used to achieve the result. $match to reduce the data(it is good to use this operator in the start of the aggregation pipeline), $unwind to unwind the students array in the Courses collection, $lookup to look in to the Students collection and get the student details

The result after executing the above aggregation query on our sample collections is

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Math101",
        "students" : 1,
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "Joseph",
                        "courses" : [
                                1,
                                3,
                                4
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Math101",
        "students" : 2,
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "Mary",
                        "courses" : [
                                1,
                                3
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Math101",
        "students" : 3,
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "Catherine",
                        "courses" : [
                                1,
                                2,
                                4
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

The efficiency on two way referencing purely based on what we retrieve, hence design your schema closely aligned with your expected results.